# How can a baseball player's average per pitch be much lower than his overall average on Fangraph?

Tags: baseball, statistics

I'm trying to figure out fangraph.com's heat maps. For example, Mike Trout's Average per Pitch looks like this: [image]

(link)[Heat Map (AVG/P)](http://www.fangraphs.com/zonegrid.aspx?playerid=10155&position=OF&ss=2017-01-01&se=2017-12-01&type=4&hand=all&count=all&blur=1&grid=10&view=bat&pitch=&season=2017)

Apparently the best he hits against pitches in any given location is 0.233 this season (as of 4/28/17), but his overall average is more than a hundred points higher at 0.337. How is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't easily find how AVG/P was calculated on these maps.  But standard averages are per at-bat, while these are per pitch.  So I would expect the per-pitch numbers to be much lower.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. He only gets one swing (or take) at each pitch, but I've seen hitters get a dozen or more pitches in a single at bat.